# Rectangle visible only in certain grid area

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

[image: screen1]

How to make the green rectangle to be visible only inside the blue one? The blue is a border of a grid. I want to cut off everything that is not inside this grid. Notice that the green rectangle will be moving.

Comment: Try to set the same margins.

Comment: If the Green rectangle is defined inside the Blue one (in XAML), then set the _ClipToBounds_ property (if it is possible for Windows Phone) of the blue border to true.

Comment: ClipToBounds should do the work, but it is not available in Windows Phone. Any workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As there is no `ClipToBounds` property in Silverlight, you would have to set the [`Clip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.clip%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property to a [`RectangleGeometry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rectanglegeometry%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

When the Grid's size is fixed, you may simply set a fixed size rectangle:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,400,600"/>
    </Grid.Clip>
    ...
</Grid>
```

When the Grid's size can change, you may set the `Clip` property in a `SizeChanged` handler:

```
<Grid SizeChanged="GridSizeChanged">
    ...
</Grid>
```

The handler code:

```
private void GridSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((UIElement)sender).Clip =
        new RectangleGeometry
        {
            Rect = new Rect(0, 0, e.NewSize.Width, e.NewSize.Height)
        };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid Width="200" Height="100">       
<Grid.Clip>
    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 200, 100"/>
</Grid.Clip>
```

source: http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/05/silverlight-cliptobounds-can-i-clip-it-yes-you-can/